# Render All Data in Slickgrid without Autoheight

Tags: slickgrid

It almost seems like this is counter to the idea of Slickgrid and I'm not sure if it's possible but I'm going to throw it out there.  I need a way to render every row of slickgrid permanently so when I scroll it's not constantly re-rendering things.  Unfortunately, `autoheight:true` as a grid option is not viable as it makes the headers disappear when scrolling, and because it's contained in an iframe (which I can't get rid of, sadly), it makes it impossible to scroll through as well.   The only other things I tried which didn't work were forceSyncScrolling and, based on the description, enableCellNavigation:false - just searching through grid options didn't give me any better ideas and I'm not sure where to go from there.

These are the current grid options I'm using:

```
    var options = {     // Grid Options
        enableCellNavigation: true,
        enableColumnReorder: false,
        multiColumnSort: true,
        rowHeight: 19
    };
```

If any other code sounds like it would be helpful to post, let me know - I am just not quite sure where to go with this.

Comment: Why do you need all of the rows rendered? Because I can't imagine a situation where that would be the "right" thing to do except for possibly printing the grid.

Comment: I couldn't agree more, but unfortunately that decision isn't up to me.